# <sec:authorize does not work in some jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I want to show the  `Authenticated user's` firstname and lastname. I put related code segment in Header.jsp and include it in two other jsp pages, `Index.jsp` and `News.jsp`.

When `Header.jsp` included in `News.jsp`, it works correctly and displays Authenticated user's firstname and lastname, but when it's include in `Index.jsp`m it doesn’t show anything.
My pages structure looks like blow:

Header.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

       <div class="usertext">
        <span id="loginedUserFullname">
             <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
               <sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" /> 
                      <sec:authentication property="principal.lastname" />
                  <span class="welcome">welcome</span>
                  <a class="logout" href='/view/cpanel/Logout.jsp'>(loge out)</a>
                  </sec:authorize>
         </span>

 </div>
</nav>
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<jsp:include page="/includes/front/Head.jsp"></jsp:include>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/includes/front/Header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <jsp:include page="/includes/front/Scripts.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
```

News.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<jsp:include page="/includes/front/Head.jsp"></jsp:include>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/includes/front/Header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <jsp:include page="/includes/front/Scripts.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
```

whats wrong with `<sec>` that doesn't work in the Index.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Index.jsp does not require the user the be authenticated but News.jsp does?